# How to build a a simple HTML5 golf game?

Tags: html, mobile, html5-canvas

I would like to do a simple HTML5 golf game. And I found this, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-ball-physics/

I've change the gravity to 0 and it works perfect for what I want! But there is a problem, when I test it on my smartphone or tablet, after I drag the ball, then the ball will immediately snap to the top left position which I think is X=0 Y=0.

How I can make this HTML5 canvas work perfectly as same as the desktop browser in my smartphone or tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the smartphone/tablet is you should implement support for [touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events) or [pointer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-pointerevents-20130219/) events. As mouse events will not be triggered for those devices.

Comment: It can be drag...but once release, the ball will stop at top left.

Comment: I guess you will have to report a bug to the authors/contributors of the KineticJS JavaScript Library as this is what the demo uses.